# sed - search in one file the contents of another

Tags: sed

So there are other similar questions, but here's in particular what I want to do -

I have one really long file. long.txt that looks like

```
line1 
line2
line3
line4
line1
line1
line2
line8
line1
line2
```

now, I have another file, pattern.txt that looks like

```
line1
line2
```

Finally, replace.txt that looks like

```
newline1
newline2
```

Is there a way to call sed such that after running it on the above, I end up with

```
newline1 
newline2
line3
line4
line1
newline1
newline2
line8
newline1
newline2
```

Comment: why one `line1` in the middle unchanged?

Comment: My pattern should specifically be `line1` on the first line followed by `line2` on the second line. I kind of specifically included a "line1" in the original file to show that it should *NOT* match the pattern being searched for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
cat <<\! >cat.sed
> :a;$!{N;ba};s/\n/\\n/ 
> !
sed ':a;$!'"{N;ba};s/$(sed -f cat.sed pattern.txt)/$(sed -f cat.sed replace.txt)/g" long.txt
newline1
newline2
line3
line4
line1
newline1
newline2
line8
newline1
newline2
```

Explanation:

- Build the LHS (pattern) and RHS (replace) of a `sed` substitution using a generic `sed` script - `cat.sed`
- Plug the above substitution into another `sed` script that processes the `long.txt` file.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ paste -d'/' pattern.txt replace.txt | sed 's@.*@s/&/@' >script.sed
$ sed -f script.sed long.txt
```